# Open graphs of facebook are not being recognize by jsf 2.0 what can I do so my open graph or meta tag to be recognized

Tags: java, jsf-2, facebook-opengraph

All the meta tag that you see on this nippets of code bellow are not being recognized by facebook button I do not know the reason, is there anyone that can explain to me why is not working. or why the meta tags are not being recognized once are in jsf page?

Thank you

```
...
xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

<h:head>
 <meta property="fb:app_id" content="YOUR-APP-ID" />
 <meta property="fb:admins" content="USER_ID,USER_ID"/>
 <meta property="og:title" content="Page Title"/>
 <meta property="og:type" content="TYPE"/>
 <meta property="og:url" content="www.youtube.com"/>
 <meta property="og:image" content="http://img.youtube.com/vi/_FiSCmL9psw/0.jpg"/>
 <meta property="og:description" content="Description of page content" />

 </h:head>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add facebook open graph on jsf 2.0 pages in order to have like button with thumbnail of a video](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/15235067/how-to-add-facebook-open-graph-on-jsf-2-0-pages-in-order-to-have-like-button-wit)

Comment: but no one gave me an answer, you guys just close the question as an ambiguous question, still I'm JSF is not able to recognize those meta tags in between <h:head>

Comment: The quality of your question has still not improved. http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: okay then let me tell you exactly what should happen. when a user click on facebook button (like) it should display on pop up kind of box what is in meta tag including the meta property="og:image" content="http://img.youtube.com/vi/_FiSCmL9psw/0.jpg"/> in this case the image as a thumbnail. Yet, this code works fine on regular html or php but not on JSF. I assume JSF needs some extra attention but I do not know what. is that clear now ?  There is planty of example how to implement facebook like button on html, php etc.. yet not on jsf. so I'm lost. hope this time is clear

Comment: There are multiple questions like this one on SO and none of them were answered. I happen to run into the same issue and would like to find a solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook OG tags Not Working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625565/facebook-og-tags-not-working)