# Facebook Open Graph meta tags not parsing

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

My website's header is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge,chrome=1'><![endif]-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.fruticultoresdearmamar.pt/images/afa-icon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ie-fixes.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/_excanvas.compiled.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie-fixes.css">
    <![endif]-->

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title>Quem Somos? | Associação de Fruticultores de Armamar</title>
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="100000536376105" />
    <meta name="fb:app_id" content="1439323016320324" />
    <meta property="og:locale" content="pt_PT" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Quem Somos? | Associação dos Fruticultores de Armamar" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.fruticultoresdearmamar.pt/conteudos/quem-somos/3" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.fruticultoresdearmamar.pt/ficheiros/conteudos/afa-quem-somos.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="A investigação, a experimentação, a demonstração e divulgação de todas as ações técnicas e económicas visando o melhoramento da fruticultura" />
```

Facebook "Share" button, doens't recognize og: meta tags, neither when i share manually hte link at facebook post.

I have also, tested at [https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.fruticultoresdearmamar.pt/conteudos/quem-somos/3) and is everything ok.

What is wrong?

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache? http://prntscr.com/3qkban

Comment: Yes, several times! This "bug" happen since 4 days ago! And it happens at diferent machines.

Comment: There are multiple questions like this one on SO and none of them were answered. I happen to run into the same issue and would like to find a solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook OG tags Not Working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625565/facebook-og-tags-not-working)